# How do I mount an SD card as read/write?

Tags: mount, filesystem, read-only, unmount

I'm trying to create an installer SD card but I can't write the image to the file system because:

```
dd: failed to open '/dev/mmcblk0p1': Read-only file system
```

The command I'm running is:

```
sudo dd if=chromiumos_image.bin of=/dev/mmcblk0p1 bs=4M
```

Any help?

Comment: Please describe how you try to do it: Which tool, or if you are using dd with a simple command line, please edit your question and show the command line, that you try to use.

Comment: The command line should be OK, provided that `/dev/mmcblk0` is the the correct target device and that it is a good card. A damaged card, that is gridlocked will be read-only. What is the output of the following command line (please edit the original question again), `grep ^/dev /etc/mtab` ; there might be one line about `/dev/mmcblk0`

Comment: You can also shut down the computer, remove all other peripheral devices (that might disturb the connection to the card), and boot again. Did things improve, so that you can write to the card? What about the card reader, can you try another card in the same reader, or try another reader (probably connected via USB) with the same card? See also this link (about USB pendrives, but it applies to memory cards too, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297

Comment: @sudodus I did have the wrong card name but I still can't write to it. I tried to (graphically) delete a file in it and it said it was read-only. I'll edit the correct name into the question.

Comment: Now I think this is wrong. I *think* that you should write to the [head of] the device, 'the whole card' `/dev/mmcblk0`, *not* to the partition `/dev/mmcblk0p1`. So the first command line was good, that is how to clone from an image file to a mass storage device, a card, a pendrive ... But I am not sure, because I do not know the content of `chromiumos_image.bin` and I do not know if you are expected to do other things too, for example install a bootloader separately. Anyway, if `/dev/mmcblk0p1` is in `/etc/mtab`, the partition is mounted and should be unmounted before you start cloning.

Comment: The following link may help. I found it searching the internet for **chromiumos_image.bin**, https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-os-discuss/4P4-4CBrHtM

Comment: @sudodus I have absolutely no clue what happened but, now, nothing is mounting nor is anything visible through any method (graphical) that I know of.

Comment: It is difficult to help, when you describe the problem in such general terms. How did things get worse than before? What did you do? Or has something important in the computer failed? Is anything visible at all (without graphical methods)?

Comment: Maybe the card is failing, but let us hope it is still good. See this link, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297

Comment: @sudodus I tried with two other cards and it didn't mount them either. I'm sorry I can't give more information. I switched from ChromeOS to Ubuntu last week so this is all very new to me.

Comment: Are you sure that you must mount the cards? Maybe it is the opposite. Running that kind of `dd` command line should usually write to a drive where no partition is mounted. **What instructions are you using? Please give us a link!** It will help us help you. Otherwise we can only guess. With some good luck, someone who have done it already will see it and chip in to help.

Comment: @sudodus [This](https://neverware.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213346247?page=1#comment_115001223167) is the link to the instructions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60513/discussion-between-amolith-and-sudodus).

Answer (score 2):

I once had a similar issue and the solution was to slide a little button on the card itself to switch between read only and read/write. This might not be the case for you but worth checking